# Ubuntu started running slowly especially the command prompt

Tags: 22.04

Recently my ubuntu machine is running very slowly. even sudo ls / takes a good 10 - 15 seconds to prompt for password. I have these apps installed

- docker (postgres, redis)
- Jetbrains PhpStorm
- Jetbrains Rider
- VSCode
- Jetbrains Intellij
- nginx

these apps have been for a very long time so I dont think they might be the cause. I have turned off stacer and jetbrains toolbox which used to run at the start. but again my machine had these things for many years.

I have tried a few solutions but nothing worked

- rename the ~/.cache and restart
- sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
- clear logs and reclaim space (using stacer)

my ubuntu version is below:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

Please note that I run ubuntu on Vmware Workstation and that has been for like 7 years. I do not know what suddenly happened. htop does not show anythign culprit, the CPU usage ( 4 processors, 16 GB RAM) shows 17% usage and memory at 4%

any solutions where should I look into the problem?

**Update**

Output pf the top command

```
  4094 myuser   20   0  905732 137600  86212 S  10.3   0.8   6:09.51 stacer                                                                                                                                      
   9972 myuser   20   0 1131.3g 205692 132480 S   2.0   1.3   0:01.60 chrome                                                                                                                                      
   3925 myuser   20   0 3990080 297084 119816 S   1.3   1.8   0:13.44 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                 
   9994 myuser   20   0 1131.3g 151436 110108 S   1.3   0.9   0:02.59 chrome                                                                                                                                      
   3717 myuser   20   0  390708 104700  70424 S   0.7   0.6   0:03.86 Xorg                                                                                                                                        
   4777 myuser   20   0  889200  52784  40676 S   0.7   0.3   0:00.76 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                                             
   9809 myuser   20   0   32.7g 189448 161100 S   0.7   1.2   0:02.74 chrome                                                                                                                                      
      1 root      20   0  167348  12728   8276 S   0.3   0.1   0:08.74 systemd                                                                                                                                     
   4020 myuser   20   0  391476  13928   7840 S   0.3   0.1   0:00.31 ibus-daemon                                                                                                                                 
   4136 myuser   20   0  140936  38276  29460 S   0.3   0.2   0:02.05 vmtoolsd                                                                                                                                    
   4510 myuser   20   0 3756204 217756  50516 S   0.3   1.3   0:21.45 jetbrains-toolb                                                                                                                             
  10206 myuser   20   0   15396   5256   4024 R   0.3   0.0   0:00.06 top                                                                                                                                         
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 kthreadd                                                                                                                                    
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                                                      
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                                                                                  
      5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 slub_flushwq                                                                                                                                
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 netns                                                                                                                                       
      8 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-events_highpri                                                                                                                 
     10 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                                                                                
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_rude_                                                                                                                             
     12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_trace                                                                                                                             
     13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.15 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                 
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:01.05 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                   
     15 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 migration/0                                                                                                                                 
     16 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                                                                               
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                                                                                     
     19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                                                                                     
     20 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1                                                                                                                               
     21 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.20 migration/1                                                                                                                                 
     22 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.22 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                                                 
     24 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-events_highpri                                                                                                                 
     25 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2                                                                                                                                     
     26 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/2                                                                                                                               
     27 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.19 migration/2                                                                                                                                 
     28 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.23 ksoftirqd/2                                                                                                                                 
     30 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H-events_highpri                                                                                                                 
     31 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3                                                                                                                                     
     32 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/3                                                                                                                               
     33 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.19 migration/3                                                                                                                                 
     34 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.11 ksoftirqd/3                                                                                                                                 
     36 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H-events_highpri                                                                                                                 
     37 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs                                                                                                                                   
     38 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 inet_frag_wq                                                                                                                                
     39 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kauditd                                                                                                                                     
     43 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd
```

Comment: Can you post output of top command?

Comment: 4% of  16GB seems suspiciously low.

Comment: First line, stacer 10% of CPU and running since 6 hours looks striking. Try  to kill -9 4094 and see if this solved your problem?

Comment: There is also another tool called nmon (apt install nmon) where you can see disk, network, cpu and other performance.

Comment: @ThomasAichinger no it never did. I believe there is something else that is causing this issue. I don't know what exactly.

Comment: Any thing of interest in the system log? Please include the output of `grep "Error" /var/log/syslog`